# Android how to get multiple email addresses of one contact user?

Tags: android, android-contacts

Let suppose in Android, a phone contact has multiple email addresses.
I need to get the email list corresponding with a specific contact list.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

use following code:

```
     Cursor emailCur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,null
                          ,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?"
                         , new String[]{id},null); 
     while (emailCur.moveToNext()) { 
                String email = emailCur.getString( emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                Log.e("Email",name+" "+email);
              } 
              emailCur.close();
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList emailList = new ArrayList<String>();

Cursor Cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", 
                            new String[]{id}, null); 
while (Cur.moveToNext()) { 
        String email = Cur.getString(Cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));                            
        emailList.add(email);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Above all answers are correct...but some more clarification..thats it:)

```
String homeEmail = emailCur.getString( emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME));

String mobileEmail = emailCur.getString( emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_MOBILE));

String workEmail = emailCur.getString( emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK));

String otherEmail = emailCur.getString( emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_OTHER));

String customEmail = emailCur.getString( emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_CUSTOM));
```